# I'd like to use `jshell` with JDK 8

Tags: java, jshell

I tried out the JDK 11 `jshell` recently and liked being able to interactively test out what's documented in core Java. My company is still tied to releasing with Java 8 though. So I thought I'd try and see if I can use the `jshell` to work with JDK 8.

*Edit* to try and explain what seems unclear: I want to use JShell, but use the Java 8 APIs for interactive mode, scripts, completion, JavaDoc etc.

My mental model of what the `jshell` was doing is: It is built with the JDK it was provided with, it therefore runs on the JRE it was built for, but I thought it loaded the JavaDoc, Auto-completions, from a JDK collection of jars, and ran the interactive scripts against another instance of the JVM, not necessarily the one with the same version as it is running on. So I thought I could control that second part with the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable.

On a Mac, my simple first attempt was to:

```
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/ \
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/jshell
```

But it's not obvious to me that this is working at all (I'll wrap some lines):

```
jshell> System.getProperties()
$3 ==> {gopherProxySet=false, awt.toolkit=sun.lwawt.macosx.LWCToolkit,
java.specification.version=11, sun.cpu.isalist=, sun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8,
java.class.path=., java.vm.vendor=Oracle Corporation, sun.arch.data.model=64, 
java.vendor.url=http://java.oracle.com/, user.timezone=, os.name=Mac OS X, 
java.vm.specification.version=11, sun.java.launcher=SUN_STANDARD, user.country=US,
sun.boot.library.path=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/lib,
sun.java.command=jdk.jshell.execution.RemoteExecutionControl 55110, 
jdk.debug=release, sun.cpu.endian=little, user.home=/Users/lamblin,
user.language=en, java.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation, 
... 
patch.level=unknown,
java.library.path=/Users/lamblin/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:., 
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation, java.vm.info=mixed mode,
java.vm.version=11.0.1+13-LTS, sun.io.unicode.encoding=UnicodeBig,
java.class.version=55.0}

jshell> System.getenv("JAVA_HOME")
$4 ==> "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/"

jshell> exit
```

Why? well the `Stream.ofNullable(T)` is new in Java 9 and while I'd like it to tell me that it's not in Java 8, it instead works pretty normally.

```
jshell> Stream.ofNullable(null).iterator().hasNext()
$3 ==> false

jshell> Stream.ofNullable("hi").iterator().hasNext()
$4 ==> true

jshell> Stream.ofNullable(
Signatures:
Stream<T> Stream<T>.<T>ofNullable(T t)

<press tab again to see documentation>

jshell> Stream.ofNullable(
Stream<T> Stream<T>.<T>ofNullable(T t)
Returns a sequential Stream containing a single element, if non-null, otherwise returns an
empty Stream .

Type Parameters:
T - the type of stream elements

Parameters:
t - the single element

Returns:
a stream with a single element if the specified element is non-null, otherwise an empty stream

<press tab again to see all possible completions; total possible completions: 544>

jshell> Stream.ofNullable(
```

Perhaps what I want isn't possible with this `jshell`.
I had started thinking it was when I saw a video using `jshell` in NetBeans on JDK 8. This video may have been misstating what was actually accomplished.

I did find that changing the class-path isn't what I'm after because that stops the `jshell` from being able to load classes it needs.

So not: `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/jshell --class-path /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/*`

It *is possible* to start the `jshell` normally and then add one of the JRE 8 jars to the class path with `/env -class-path /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar`. This can be done with with all the jars in `jre/lib` but it won't unload or replace what was loaded, so it doesn't end up giving you an environment limited to running Java 8 snippets.

Comment: what is not working for you? and what does the `jshell --version` on your command line reads?

Comment: Sorry, but the question does not quite make sense. What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to use JShell, but restrict the Java APIs accessible to scripts to JDK 8?

Comment: @sleske yes.
I'm glad you understood while asking the question.

Comment: @dlamblin: Well, then you might consider editing your question to make this clear :-). Right now, your question is first listing what you tried and how it failed, only then do you explain (in passing) what you really _want_. I'd suggest reversing this: First explain what you want to achieve, then show what you tried. Makes things clearer...

Comment: @sleske you commented while I was editing. I hope it's clearer.

Comment: @nullpointer it reports 11.0.1 which is what I would expect. It still fits with the model I just edited into my question.

Comment: *"It is possible to start ...."* - Yea, that won't work.  Read about the "bootclasspath".

Comment: @StephenC BTW thanks all, I was quite confused in the level of coupling, but after reading up its clear that both the interpreter (naturally) and the interpreted statements (to my disappointment, but understandably) are closely tied to the JVM the jshell interpreter runs in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not using using `jshell` in Java 8.

```
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/ \
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/jshell
```

Why?  Because JDK tools don't actually use $JAVA_HOME to decide which JVM to use.  Instead the decision is made by the executable (or wrapper script) based on its file location.

But you can confirm this by running `jshell -version`.  (Note: only one `-`!!)

---

If you download the OpenJDK source, you can see that `jshell` is mostly implemented in Java. And it has a main method. So you *might* be able to compile the `jshell` classes with a Java 8 compiler.  But that is likely to fail<sup>1</sup>, because `jshell` knows about modules, and that means it has dependencies on module-related API changes that were made in Java 9.

But ... why bother?

> Why? well the `Stream.ofNullable(T)` is new in Java 9 and while I'd like it to tell me that it's not in Java 8, it instead works pretty normally.

1. The Java 8 compiler will tell you that.   So will an IDE, assuming you set the platform dependencies.
2. You might be able to use the `-C` option to get `jshell` to compile your code against the Java 8 APIs.

---

<sup>1 - If you put in the effort to work around these anticipated dependencies, and other Java 9+ dependencies in the jshell classes, then you will have succeeded in backporting it to Java 8.  Fame and fortune awaits you :-)</sup>

Comment: And since `jshell` was added in Java 9, it's not going to work on JDK8.

Comment: @Thilo right; the built `jshell` tool can only work on the JRE it was built against; I assume tools distributed with a JDK target that JRE. But I do not want to run it on the JRE for 8... so much as have the interaction, statements and jdoc etc. limited/using JDK 8. I take it the tool is not able to split what JRE it's running in and which JRE its interactively provided statements are running in.

Comment: @StephenC I assumed `jshell` was less coupled with the runtime environment than it is in.
Sure, I definitely would rather just use the latest JDK and use the jshell in it.

Comment: Well, if you look at the manual entry for "jshell" the coupling with modules is clear.   You may be able to decouple it, but I predict it would be a lot of work.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I do - I have both Java 8 and Java 17, I escape to Java 17 momentarily for the jshell session ...

```
jshell() {
  export JAVA_HOME=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjdk/17/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home
  /usr/bin/jshell "$@"
  export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-8.jdk/Contents/Home
}
```

I add the above bash function to my `~/.bash_profile`

While this may not be the perfect way, at least I can try out few things that are common across Java 8 and Java 17 ...

```
~ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_302"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Temurin)(build 1.8.0_302-b08)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Temurin)(build 25.302-b08, mixed mode)

~ jshell
|  Welcome to JShell -- Version 17
|  For an introduction type: /help intro

jshell> String s = "abc"
s ==> "abc"

jshell> s
s ==> "abc"

jshell> s.charAt(1)
$4 ==> 'b'

jshell> /exit
|  Goodbye

~ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_302"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Temurin)(build 1.8.0_302-b08)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Temurin)(build 25.302-b08, mixed mode)
```

Comment: As stated in Stephen's answer, this doesn't actually do anything. Your jshell terminal is still java 17 compliant. This is because the jshell on your PATH is the one inside your java 17 JDK, and uses the libraries within the same installation.